# How to animate an object vertically with touch like Spotify's music player does when tapping the song,

Tags: xcode, drag, tap

Im using Xcode, and when i tap/drag on my imageView at the bottom of the screen, I want it to be brought up and reveal all of it on screen similiar to the way Spotify does it when you click the banner at the bottom. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using spring animations if you want a nice animation like this:

```
func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton!) { //or in an IBAction
    let duration: NSTimeInterval = 0.75
    let damping: CGFloat = 1
    let velocity: CGFloat = 0.5

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping: damping, initialSpringVelocity: velocity, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.myView.center.y = self.view.frame.height/2
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Sorry for Swift code, if you're not able to translate it then let me know :)

**Edit**
For Objective-C the code would look something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75, delay:0, usingSpringWithDamping:1, initialSpringVelocity:0.5, options:UIViewAnimationOptionsCurveLinear, animations:^{
    //Animations
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //Completion Block
}];
```

Comment: If you could translate it to Objective-C that would really help me out. Im just getting used to Objective C so Swift is way out of my reach.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. I made a button and included this code to trigger the animation:

```
self.moveX.constant = 200;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 200.0f, imageView.frame.size.width,imageView.frame.size.height);
}];
```