# "Spotify like" dragging bottom player in swift

Tags: ios, swift, drag, uiviewanimation

I would like to have a bar/button at the bottom of my screen that behaves like the  mini player bar on Spotify. If I click on it, a view appears from the bottom. If I drag it, I can play with it and make it go up and down. And if I release it, it continues up by itself.

I checked that question: [How to animate an object vertically with touch like Spotify's music player does when tapping the song,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881214/how-to-animate-an-object-vertically-with-touch-like-spotifys-music-player-does) but it only resizes an (image) view where I want to put a new ViewController (and I cannot drag it, only click it).

I found a project that does that: https://github.com/andriirogulin/ARSlidingPanel and it looks like it works pretty well. It is really something like that that I want to achieve.

My problem is that I have almost no knowledge of objective-C. Moreover I tried to follow the Integration tutorial and I cannot add a custom segue from ARSPContainerController. I need to drague it from an object, and there is none in the sample project. Therefore I would like to know if:

1. there is a name for this kind of specific bottom bar (for easier research purposes) and the way I would like to use it.
2. there is a Pod/project that does that in swift.
3. someone has a sample project that has this behaviour?

Comment: For more functionalities, you can look this: https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController This popup view combines a player inside.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isn't it very close to what Apple Music is doing? If so, you might be able to use this: https://github.com/xxxAIRINxxx/MusicPlayerTransition